# Vim can't properly be launched by cscope

Tags: vim, cscope

I use *cscope* on a large project, *7zip*.
I generate the *cscope* database and run the command `cscope -d`, then I search for the C symbol `main`, I choose one, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I get this:

```
cchaney@localhost 7zipsources$ cscope -d
Error detected while processing /home/cchaney/.vimrc:
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
line   29:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
line   30:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'a.vim'
line   31:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'molokai'
line   32:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
line   33:
E492: Not an editor command:  Plugin 'unimpaired.vim'
line   64:
E518: Unknown option: autochdir
line   89:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
line   94:
E518: Unknown option: foldenable
line   95:
E518: Unknown option: foldmethod=syntax
line   96:
E518: Unknown option: foldcolumn=0
line   97:
E518: Unknown option: foldlevel=1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This is weird, because everything is fine when I open the file directly in *vim*.

What's going on? How may I fix this?

**UPDATE**======

Cscope launched vi instead of vim. So , how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be that you might've got multiple versions of *vim* installed, and you have `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` set to a really old version?

Comment: @Kusalananda no. I didn't do anything to that two env variable

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. I asked whether they were set to an older version of *vim*. I don't know *cscope*, but are you able to configure what editor to launch somewhere, and is that editor the same as when you just type `vim` on the command line?

Comment: @Kusalananda It shows me nothing when i type `echo $EDITOR` or `echo $VISUAL`,  is that abnormal?

Comment: No, it's not, but it seems *cscope* is launching a very old version of *vim* somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting vim as your cscope's default editor

```
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
```

Make sure that you add this line in your `.bash_profile` file so you don't have to manually do it every time.

See section ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in [cscope man page](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html)